# First integral for non-linear system of equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the dynamics

\begin{align}
x'&=y\\
y'&=-y-x-x^2\tag1
\end{align}

which represents a one-dimensional mechanical system with velocity $y$ and coordinate $x$, or in other words the second order equation

$$x''=-y-x-x^2 \Longleftrightarrow x''+g(x)=0 \tag2$$

where $g(x)=y+x+x^2.$ Since the origin is an asymptotically stable equilibrium point, I want to find its region of attraction using an appropriate Lyapunov function $V(x,y)$. So in the book they give the formula

$$V(x,y)=\text{Kinetic energy}+\text{Potential energy}=\frac{y^2}{2}+\int_0^xg(z)dz, \tag3$$

plugging in my expression for $g(z)$ I get

$$V(x,y)=\frac{y^2}{2}+\int_0^xy+z+z^2 \ dz=\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+xy.\tag4$$

However, according to the book the $xy$ should not be at the end. I assume it is because they get their $g(x)$ to be $g(x)=x+x^2$. How come?

Comment: Should $eq(2)$ not be written as $x''=-x'-x-x^2$?

Comment: If I do that, I still get an $x$ at the end of $V(x,y)$ instead of $xy$, which is still wrong.

Comment: The system has dissipation so it collapses into a point through a spiral sink.

Comment: @Cesareo - I know it's a spiral sink but I don't understand how it causes the $y$ to vanish in my $g(x)$.

Comment: For small $|x|$ we have the dynamics reduced to $$ x'=y\\ y'=-x-y$$. so $(x x'+y y')' = -y^2$ or $\frac 12\frac{d}{dt}(x^2+y^2) = -y^2$

Comment: Writing $g(x)=y+x+x^2$ doesn't make much sense to begin with, since the right-hand side depends on $x$ **and** $y$, not only on $x$.

Comment: @HansLundmark - So what do you suggest taking $g(x)$ as? Even if I take $g(x)=x'+x+x^2$ I still get an incorrect answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no $y$ in $g(x)$, the idea is wrong from the start. As $y$ is not an argument of $g$, the variable $y$ can not appear in $g$.

Thus it is correct to write $g(x)=x+x^2$ so that the potential energy is $G(x)=\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3$.

Using that in the Lyapunov function gives 
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{y^2}2+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3)=-y^2
$$
and it is easy to check that there are no solutions that move along the $x$ axis except the stationary solutions with $y=0$, $x=-1$ or $x=0$. This means that this energy function is continuously decreasing. If a solution starts in the valley around the origin, it will descend towards the origin.

Comment: So in choosing the function $g(x)$ I can simply ignore all the terms containing $y$? The whole of the question was to motivate the choice of $g(x)=x+x^2$, how does one come up with it?

Comment: If you take the second-order formulation and multiply with $x'$, you get $$x''x'+x'^2+(x+x^2)x'=0.$$ The first and the last term are directly integrable and can be assembled into an energy function, the middle term has no obvious anti-derivative, is always positive and thus reduces the energy in the balance, which is also called dissipation, or friction.

Comment: I honestly feel like a chimpanzee for still not getting how to obtain $g(x)=x+x^2$ form your comment. How do you go from the equation in your comment to $g(x)=x+x^2?$

Comment: You want to compare your equation to an equation for physical motion. In general that has the form (dividing out mass factors) $x''+c(x,x')x'+g(x)=0$ where the friction coefficient $c(x,x')$ is always non-negative and $g$ is a conservative force, the gradient of some potential function. So in your equation you check that the second derivative has coefficient $1$ and assemble all terms that are purely in $x$ into the function $g$. Not all second order ODE fall in this scheme, so you can not compare them to a physical system.

Comment: But in my case I have that $c(x,x')=x+x^2$, so how is $g(x)=x+x^2$? Also $$\int_0^x x''x'+(x')^2+(x+x^2)x' dx = \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+x\neq G(x).$$

Comment: Compare the equations before and after multiplying with $x'$, after for the last form would be $$x''x'+c(x,x')x'^2+g(x)x'=0$$ which integrates to $$\frac12x'^2+\int g(x)dx=-\int c(x,x')x'^2dt.$$ In short, $c(x,x')=1$ for the given equation.